# ionic cordova build ios Error: spawn EPERM ionic 3

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have this error when i try ionic cordova build ios

```
Error: spawn EPERM

at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:313:11)
at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:503:9)
at spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js:12:24)
at spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/utils/shell.js:136:12)
at ShellCommand.spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/utils/shell.js:125:16)
at ShellCommand.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/utils/shell.js:87:24)
at Shell.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/shell.js:34:37)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:104:62)
at <anonymous>
```